# Transfer File through UDP in Java. How to detect end of file at Server?

Tags: java, networking, udp

At Client I chunks buffer with `Arrays.CopyofRange()` from 1 `FileEvent` object:

```
byte[] data = outputStream.toByteArray();
for (int i = 0; i <= data.length; i += incommingData.length) {             
    byte[] forSent = new byte[0x3ff];
    forSent = Arrays.copyOfRange(data, i, i + 1023);
    DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(forSent, forSent.length, ipAddress, PORT);
    socket.send(sendPacket);
    System.out.println("File sent from client : " + i);
}
String done = "Done";
DatagramPacket stringDone = new DatagramPacket(done.getBytes(), done.length(), ipAddress, PORT);
socket.send(stringDone);
```

And at Server:

```
do {
    byte[] incomingData = new byte[1024 * 1000 * 50];
    incomingPacket = new DatagramPacket(incomingData, incomingData.length);
    socket.receive(incomingPacket);
    byte[] data ;
    data = incomingPacket.getData();
    result = Arrays.copyOfRange(data, 0, data.length);
    System.out.println("Da nhan:" + result.length);
    message = new String(incomingPacket.getData(), 0, incomingPacket.getLength());
    System.out.println(message);
} while ( !message.equals("Done"));
```

after send all buffer, i send 1 String "done". And at Server i check end of file by String "done". But it not work, via UDP, how can i detect end of file transfer. Thanks!

Comment: Detecting that the last block has been received is about the same as detecting that any other block has been received (and assembled in order).  Which, if you don't have, means you have a really unreliable transfer program.

Answer (score 2):

UDP is an unreliable protocol.  Messages may be lost without either the sender or receiver being notified.  This is particularly likely if the sender sends a large number of messages in quick succession ... as your code is liable to do.

So I suspect that what is happening in your case is that the message that contains the "done" string is being lost.

---

There is no easy cure for this using UDP.  It would entail implementing flow control, message loss detection and retransmission ... at the application protocol level.  This is technically possible, but it is simpler to either switch to TCP, or look for an alternative *reliable* protocol.

Comment: +1 Generally speaking, implementing a point to point protocol over UDP is about as fast/complicated as UDP, except for UDP you have to do all the work/testing yourself, for TCP this is written and tested over decades for you.

Comment: Thanks. I used Thread.sleep(15) to slow send file. But what another way to detect end of file send from Client? Thank you very much ?

Comment: @L4mbd4 - You need to handle that in the *design* of your application-level file transfer protocol.  There are various ways to do it.  I don't particularly want to explain it because I don't want to encourage you to waste your time *doing this the wrong way*.  And UDP >>is<< the wrong way.  Hint: `sleep(15)` is a band-aid.  It doesn't fix the problem *reliably*.

Answer (score 0):

From the app that sends the file, Send a new packet after transferring your file.
For ex.

```
DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket("[END OF UDP STREAM]".getBytes(), 19, ip, port);
```

Then from the receiving end, detect if the packet is equal to the end string then break out of the loop that receives it.

```
if (Arrays.equals("[END OF UDP STREAM]".getBytes(), Arrays.copyOf(buff, 19)))
{
    System.out.println("END OF STREAM DETECTED");
    break;
}
```

*buff being the byte[] array that buffers the datgram packet

Comment: How does this differ from the OP's code where he sends 'Done'?